# Appium server will not start from Eclipse through Java on a Mac

Tags: java, server, appium

When I try to start my Appium server from eclipse with Java, I get the failure message “org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused”
I’ve been puzzling over this and I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Here is the console log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building TestngCucumberBoilerPlate 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ TestngCucumberBoilerPlate ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/<redacted>/Documents/BlueprintTestngCucumber/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ TestngCucumberBoilerPlate ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:testResources (default-testResources) @ TestngCucumberBoilerPlate ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ TestngCucumberBoilerPlate ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ TestngCucumberBoilerPlate ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/<redacted>/Documents/BlueprintTestngCucumber/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
entered start server
commands given
Attempting to start server
Appium server started.
capabilities Set.
cucumberrunner.takescreenshot
Tests run: 5, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 6.01 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
setUp(main.CucumberRunner)  Time elapsed: 5.702 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused
Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'
System info: host: '<redacted>-0046.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1048:a7a5:ee69:6124%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:337)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:254)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:83)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:93)
    at main.CucumberRunner.setUp(CucumberRunner.java:231)

takeScreenshot(main.CucumberRunner)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at main.CucumberRunner.takeScreenshot(CucumberRunner.java:300)

quit(main.CucumberRunner)  Time elapsed: 0.021 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at main.CucumberRunner.quit(CucumberRunner.java:336)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  CucumberRunner.quit:336 NullPointer
  CucumberRunner.setUp:231 » WebDriver Connection refused
Build info: version: '...
  CucumberRunner.takeScreenshot:300 NullPointer

Tests run: 5, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.736 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-13T13:00:57-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/1206M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project TestngCucumberBoilerPlate: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/<redacted>/Documents/BlueprintTestngCucumber/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Here is my code for Appium server class. I get the error whenever I do start server, then try to connect to the server.

public class AppiumServer {

```
public void startServer() {
    System.out.println("entered start server");
    CommandLine command = new CommandLine(
            "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node");
    command.addArgument(
            "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js",
            false);
    command.addArgument("--address", false);
    //command.addArgument("http://localhost:");
    command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");
    command.addArgument("--port", false);
    command.addArgument("4723");
    command.addArgument("--full-reset", false);
    System.out.println("commands given");
    DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();




    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setExitValue(1);
    System.out.println("Attempting to start server");
    try {
        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);


        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Appium server started.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopServer() {
    String[] command = { "/usr/bin/killall", "-KILL", "node" };
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        System.out.println("Appium server stopped.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the calling class, up until the point of failure. This class successfully connects if I start the server manually by opening Appium. I’m pretty sure the server isn’t starting when I try to start it through eclipse.

```
public static AppiumServer server = new AppiumServer();
@BeforeSuite
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

System.out.println("Before suite started.");

server.startServer();

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    // Set ios deviceName desired capability. Set your device name.
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "My iPhone");
    // Set BROWSER_NAME desired capability. It’s iOSin our case here.
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
    // Set iOS VERSION desired capability. Set your mobile device’s OS version.
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "11.2.6");
    // Set iOS platformName desired capability. It’s Android in our case here.
    capabilities.setCapability("noReset", false);
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    //capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
    // Set your application’s appPackage if you are using any other app.
    capabilities.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.<redacted>.<redacted>.<redacted>");
    // It will launch app in iOS device.
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "<redacted>");
    capabilities.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", "<redacted>");
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
    capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", "com.<redacted>.<redacted>");
    System.out.println("capabilities Set.");


    driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    System.out.println("connection suceeded");
```

Comment: I could be mistaken since i no longer launch my Appium server that way, I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be using appium.js but **main.js**

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions:

`Connection refused` means the Appium server cannot handle the incoming request due to some reasons.

**1.check possible local issues**

Check that there isn't already started same process, or process with same port.

**2. Think as server-based**

or simply don't run Appium each time You try to test, open server and leave it as server supposed to behave, running all of the time, and handle requests when is needed.
In start I've also tried this method, by running server programmatically, but it is really not necessary, it is slower, need maintenance, and You have to it start always.
My opinion is this is time-consuming, and not necessary. Start it from command line/console, there are various ways to do it, node.js, shell script , Appium server IDE.

here is simplest command (from mac) `appium --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723`

**3. possible solution via `AppiumDriverLocalService`**

```
AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver=null;
AppiumDriverLocalService service=null;

service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();  
capabilities.setCapability("platormName", "Android");  
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "yourAppUdid");  
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","YourAppPackage");  
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","yourAppActivity"); 


(or IOS)
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
// Set ios deviceName desired capability. Set your device name.
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "My iPhone");
// Set BROWSER_NAME desired capability. It’s iOSin our case here.
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "iOS");
// Set iOS VERSION desired capability. Set your mobile device’s OS version.
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "11.2.6");
// Set iOS platformName desired capability. It’s Android in our case here.
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", false);
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
//capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
// Set your application’s appPackage if you are using any other app.
capabilities.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.<redacted>.<redacted>.<redacted>");
// It will launch app in iOS device.
capabilities.setCapability("udid", "<redacted>");
capabilities.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", "<redacted>");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", "com.<redacted>.<redacted>");
System.out.println("capabilities Set.");

service.start();

driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(service, capabilities);
```

**Note : If you are using appium version 1.5.3 or greater then you have to set APPIUM_BINARY_PATH in environmental variable.**

e.g. APPIUM_BINARY_PATH=...\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js

Hope this helps,